# How to get my word from following string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have two strings in PHP:

```
$Str1 = "/welcome/files/birthday.php?business_id=0";
$Str2 = "/welcome/index.php?page=birthday";
```

I have to get word birthday from this two string with a single function.
I need a function which returns birthday on both case.

example

```
function getBaseWord($word){ 
    ...
    return $base_word;
}

getBaseWord('/welcome/files/birthday.php?business_id=0');
getBaseWord('/welcome/index.php?page=birthday');
```

both function call should return "birthday".

How can i do it.

Comment: Um, maybe `function getBirthdayFromString($str) { return 'birthday'; }`? Please provide more information what this ‘birthday’ actually is.

Comment: Are these PHP variable Strings? Or are they actually URLs?

Comment: they are strings. returned value of **echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]**

Comment: Ahh, I interpreted that as to actual URLs, please try and make your questions clear as i have edited the above ^.^ I will make adjustments to my answer.

Comment: you have got actually what i mean. thnx

Comment: Not a problem. Be sure to mark your question as solved if i helped you so that in the future it may help someone again. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you will need to do is get all of the actual GET variables extracted from the string:

```
//Seperate the URL and the GET Data
list($url,$querystring) = explode('?', $string, 2);

//Seperate the Variable name from its value
list($GETName, $GETValue) = explode("=", $querystring);

//Check to see if we have the right variable name
if($GETName == "page"){
    //Return the value of that variable.
    return $GETValue;
}
```

**NOTE**

This is very BASIC and will not accept more then one GET parameter. You will need to modify it if you plan on have more variables.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check it once. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: no i haven't down voted you... there was mistake on my question before edit.

Comment: Hi @KrishnaKarki, If this helped you to solve your problem, it would be best if you marked the question as solved so that it may at some point help others in the future! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 3):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to do then this should do what you need:

```
function getWord(){
     return $_GET['page'];
}
```

or $_GET['business_id'];

I think $_GET is an associative array made from the GET request that was sent to the page. An associative array is one where you access something like ['name of the element'] instead of [1] or [2] or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are talking about but, you can cut the word "birthday" with str_replace and replace with another word, or you can find the position with stripos, I have no idea what we are trying to do here, so those are the only things come to my mind